# HighCharts: Increase width and padding of stacked bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I am trying to increase the `width` and `padding` of stacked bar graph but unable to get it. I have tried `pointWidth` and `pointPadding` property but it overlaps with each other if I try to give `pointWidth: 20`but it overlaps with each other instead of having padding among bars.

```
plotOptions: {

            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                 pointWidth: 15
                pointPadding: 0
            }
        },
```

Please look at the below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/rkahuja99/cmhbvqp7/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The width and padding of the bars? or the entire graph as a whole?

Comment: width and padding of whole bars of the graph

Comment: Are you able to change the height of the `div` you're using as the chart? Right now it's limited to 400px so it can't give you the padding you want.

Comment: You can't use `pointWidth` and `pointPadding`. Use just one of them. And Highcharts won't resize container to fit all bars just because you set `pointWidth` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height appears to be fixed rather than resizing to fit the contents. According to the [documentation for chart.height](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.height):

> By default the height is calculated from the offset height of the containing element, or 400 pixels if the containing element's height is 0.

Since you have specified the height of the containing element to be 400px, the bars cannot fit in the chart without overlapping.

Unfortunately, removing the height styling from the containing element does not cause the chart to resize itself to fit the contents either, as the container will have a height of zero by default, defaulting the chart height to 400px.

You'll have to set the height manually, either by increasing the container's height or by setting the height of the chart (any combination of these seem to work).

Comment: Thank you. Adjusting the height of div fixed the problem.